# How to create bootable USB without administrator rights?

Tags: boot, usb, disk

I would like to use the work computer to create the bootable USB

I need bootable USB disk for my home computer.

I'm not administrator on the work computer, so I can't execute the installer.

Is there another way?

Comment: The possible solutions depend on: 1. the operating system of the work computer; 2.  If you can reboot the work computer from a CD/DVD/USB drive; 3. If you can write to a CD/DVD/USB drive from the work computer. -- It might be easier to use a friend's computer.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not. Non-administrators can not change the MBR.

Maybe if you have the Virtual box at work. And have access to USB.

It is also possible to write a bootable CD. Use the application Brasero.

You could ask your IT department at work to make a bootable USB for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can boot the Ubuntu Live CD, (or Live USB), you should be able to run Startup Disk Creator.

Comment: If you can boot an Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB, you have administrator rights (in the live system).

Comment: Well isn't that the largest chicken and the egg response.  Can't create a cd, to boot to the cd, to create the cd...

Comment: @triunenature LOL! I had to log in just to upvote your comment

Answer (score 0):

unetbootin (for windows) does not need admin rights to create bootable USB sticks from the distro of choice.

Comment: This is simply wrong. You do need admin privileges to us unetbootin. I just tried it.